# How to add v1 when specifying the URL of an API?

Tags: 7, services

I'm creating an API service using Services (Drupal 7) and would like to create an URL like /api/avu/v1/{id}.

I have *api* in Path to endpoint and in hook_services_resources() I have $resources['avu'] with

```
"args" => array(
   array(
     "name" => "id",
     "optional" => false,
     "source" => array("path" => 0),
     "type" => "int",
     "description" => "The id of the course to retrieve."
   )
),
```

So /api/avu/{id} works but I can't figure out how to add v1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was to add another argument and clear the cache.

```
"args" => array(
   array(
     "name" => "version",
     "optional" => false,
     "source" => array("path" => 0),
     "type" => "string",
     "description" => "The API version."
   ),
   array(
     "name" => "id",
     "optional" => false,
     "source" => array("path" => 1),
     "type" => "int",
     "description" => "The id of the course to retrieve."
   )
),
```